# All combinations of dependant vectors fill space?

Tags: linear-algebra

In attempting to learn linear algebra I'm working through Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra", 4th ed. and (embarrassingly) am stuck on the first problem.

The problem is:

Describe Geometrically (line, plane, or all of $\mathbf{R}^3$) all linear combinations of:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
           2 \\
           0 \\           
           0
         \end{bmatrix}\text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           2 \\           
           2
         \end{bmatrix}\text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
           2 \\
           2 \\
           2
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

To me, it seems that since the third vector is the sum of the first two, this should fill a plane inside of $\textbf{R}^3$ (specifically, containing all points for which $y=z$).

However, in the back of the book, the answer is "all of $\textbf{R}^3$". I must be missing something, but how can this be? What combination of these vectors produces the point $(x=0,y=1,z=2)$ for example?

Given that (1) this is the first problem in the book and that (2) I couldn't find any errata mentioning this, and (3) that I am a noob, I am inclined to think the problem is my understanding rather than a mistake in the book.

Comment: The book is wrong - for example there is no way to reach the point $$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$Either that, or the question has a typo and those vectors aren't what they should be.

Comment: You beat the book! Keep it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of having an answer, note that the author is wrong: any vector $(x,y,z)$ with $y\ne z$ is clearly not a linear combination of the three mentioned vectors.